# Get back reset hard commit from GIT

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I've hard reset to a particular commit. After do that my changes are gone. Can I get back my changes in git?

I'd following steps.

```
git reset --hard [commit id]
git push origin [branch name] --force
```

Comment: Unstaged changes are lost.  To retrieve committed changes, try `git reflog`

Comment: I'd that. But I can't see anything.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamPursell it's working like a charm. Sorry first I wrongly saw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
As @William mentioned, reflog should do the trick
Look at the image above of git reflog. I followed the following steps:

1. First commit
2. second commit
3. Hard reset to first commit
4. Force push the changes.
5. Next, `git reset 83a0402` which is the sha for the second commit.

You should be able to see your changes now